# Unable to add tag to Azure pipeline during build

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I want to tag my pipeline build during the build process itself. For which based on the official document I tried `echo ##vso[build.addbuildtag]testing` in the pipeline yaml. There was no error but the build was not tagged either.

I'm able to add tags from portal successfully.

My pipleine yaml below.

```
pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

jobs:
- job: addingtag
  displayName: addingtag
  steps:
  - script: |
        echo ##vso[build.addbuildtag]testing
    displayName: addingtag
```

Below are other combinations I tried and still failed.
`echo ##vso[build.addbuildtag] testing`
`echo ##vso[build.addbuildtag]Tag_testing`

Comment: Can you add what agent you use ? (microsoft hosted windows/ubuntu/etc.) Try the following instead -> write-host "##vso[build.addbuildtag]testing" if you are using a windows-agent

Comment: I'm using ubuntu. Can't switch to powershell as I have other linux commands unrelated to this and they work fine too. Will add the info to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may need to add double quotes, I could successfully add tag by using YAML script like below.

```
- script: |
    echo "##vso[build.addbuildtag]testing"
  displayName: addingtag
```

Comment: Worked like charm. High time Microsoft updates their document. Will award the bounty after 22 hours.